# Django many to many relation with admin panel display

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I want to do a many to many relation in Django and display a list of variables in the admin panel.

I found the documentation a little bit complicated to understand and I am unable to make this work.

This are my files:

models.py

```
class LanguageFramework(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=False, null=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return(str(self.name))

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)
    languages_frameworks = models.ManyToManyField(LanguageFramework)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=10000, blank=False, null=False)
    github_link = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=False, null=False)
    post_link = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=False, null=False)


class ProjectsGotFrameworks(models.Model):
    project_id = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None)
    language_framework_id = models.ForeignKey(LanguageFramework, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None)
```

admin.py

```
class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['name','languages_frameworks']
    list_display = ('name','languages_frameworks')
    filter_horizontal = ('languages_frameworks')
    fieldsets = [
        ('Project info',{'fields': ['name','description']}),
        ('External',{'fields': ['github_link','post_link']}),
    ]
```

So what I want, is to display a list of all LanguagesFrameworks elements in the ProjectAdmin page and let me select which ones of the list are in one project.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That should work without doing anything. What ere you getting when you remove the fieldsets.

Comment: @admin.register(ModelName)

Comment: Of course I have tried this.

Comment: Finally, I noticed that filter_horizontal needs to be a list. So I changed properly and it works.